# Скрипт для перемещения файлов

Tags: python, cmd, bat

Требуется написать скрипт, который будет запускаться в шедулере на windows сервере каждую 1 минут.
Он будет сканировать папку `d:\111` и, в зависимости какой там появится файл, копировать его в нужную папку, а исходный файл отправлять в архив.
Например:
 
Появился файл в `d:\111\`, имя которого начинается на **"А"**, скопировать файл в `e:\a-files`, а затем сам файл переместить в архив `d:\111\arch`.
Появился потом файл в `d:\111\`, имя которого начинается на **"B"**, скопировать файл в `e:\b-files`, а затем сам файл переместить в архив `d:\111\arch`.

Comment: Можно так, например,
@echo off
if exist d:\111\a??????????.* xcopy d:\111\a??????????.* e:\a-files\ /V /Y
if exist d:\111\b??????????.* xcopy d:\111\b??????????.* e:\b-files\ /V /Y
move d:\111\a??????????.* d:\111\arch
move d:\111\b??????????.* d:\111\arch

???

Comment: Изучите цикл for. Там можно весь алфавит указать.
for /?

Comment: конечно можно, для этого используйте сортировку файлов. Например, через парсинг вывода листинга файлов: **for /f %i in ('dir /a-d /b /o-d D:\111') do ....**